# Qt LineEdit setInputMask() with setText() and QRegExp

Tags: qt, qlineedit, qregexp, qdate

I have a `QLineEdit` for Date in `mm/dd/yyyy` format. I am getting input using the keyboard and not using `QDateEdit` because of the requirement. And when the `lineEdit` comes to view, it has to show to the user the current date. I need the following for the `lineEdit`.

1. I need the two slashes always to be displayed and the cursor has to skip while entering or deleting.
2. I should not allow the user to enter an invalid date i.e while entering itself the `lineEdit` should not get invalid numbers.
3. I have to set the current date as the default text when the `lineEdit` comes to view.

For the first point, I tried using `setInputMask("99/99/9999")` but with this I can't set the current date using `setText()`. And how to use `QRegExp` to not to allow `lineEdit` get an invalid number while employing `setInputMask()`?

Answer (score 1):

[QDateEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdateedit.html) will serve your purpose.

1. use `setDisplayFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")`.
2. `QDateEdit` wont allow invalid  dates
3. You can use `QDateEdit::setDate()` obtained from 
   `QDateTime::currentDateTime()`

Comment: I am not supposed to use it. I have to use QLineEdit.

Answer (score 1):

For setting text into `QLineEdit` with `setInputMask("99/99/9999")` you should format text depending on your mask:

```
lineEdit.setText("{:02d}/{:02d}/{:04d}".format(m, d, y))
```

Alternatively, you can temporary disable InputMask, format your date without `/`, set it and re-enable InputMask. *But make sure that number of symbols in every part is correct.*

```
lineEdit.setInputMask("")
lineEdit.setText(date_str.replace("/", ""))
lineEdit.setInputMask("99/99/9999")
```